Bluetooth communication between 2 Arduinos using HC-05
I am trying to send sensor values from an MPU6050 Accelerometer from one Arduino to another continuously using 2 HC-05 modules, one on each Arduino. I have done the following:

Entered AT Mode on both HC-05 and set one as master and another as slave using AT+ROLE.

Paired the modules (Apparently) by entering the slave's Address in the AT+BIND as well as the AT+PAIR command on the master.

All this was done while RX was connected to Arduino's RX and the same for TX.

Tried sending sample values (like small integers and strings) using the Serial.read() and Serial.write() functions after exiting AT Mode. (TX and RX remained connected to the same)


After these steps, the master is receiving -1 values no matter what is sent in Serial.write() on the slave. This problem is very persistent and I feel like I am missing some fundamental steps, but can't figure it out from anywhere.
Please point out if I am doing something wrong or missing something important. I deeply appreciate any help.
I also tried the SoftwareSerial library and the BTSerial.read and BTSerial.write commands, still there is no avail.

Ensure that TX of the master HC-05 is connected to RX of the Arduino and vice versa for both modules.
Use voltage dividers for TX from HC-05 to RX on Arduino if using a 5V Arduino since HC-05 operates at 3.3V logic.
Check for loose connections or bad jumper wires.
